# How to cleanse a string to avoid SQL Injection and the most common types of attack? (in PHP)

Tags: php, security, filter, sql-injection, user-input

Is there a way to, in as little code as possible, to filter a string for both SQL injection and the most common forms of attack?

In my scripts I'm using the following, I would like to know whether it's reasonably safe and whether someone else has a suggestion:

```
$cleanName    = htmlspecialchars(addslashes($dirtyName));
```

See how I filtered it both for html chars and for quotes and double-quotes.

NOTE: I'm using `addslashes()` rather than `mysql_real_escape_string()` because I don't want to hardcode the DB I'm using into my code.

Is this ok?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you will find countless posts on SO and elsewhere to answer your question if you search for "prepared statements".  You will likely find that you may need to abandon regular "mysql" queries and functions asap, to be replaced with mysqli and pdo prepared statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably not... you need to escape your raw text for each purpose separately for which you are going to use it:

- For GET requests, use `urlencode`.
- For HTML output, use `htmlentities`.
- For calling as a command via `system`, use `escapeshellcmd`.
- For passing arguments to a command via `system`: use `escapeshellargs`.
- For passing a database parameter: use `mysql_real_escape_string`.

There's no "universal" solution for magically escaping text. Keep raw text internally, and escape it for the appropriate purpose.

Comment: is `mysql_real_escape_string` only for mysql or somethign similar exists for postgres?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind recoding your connection and a couple extra lines of you code you can't beat PDO for security.  It uses the C backend to prepare and execute your mysql queries.  So instead of string concatenation you get predefined sections in the query that must be value XYZ.  One of the guys here on stackoverflow explained it like this:

Imagine a hotdog stand.  You walk up to the hotdog stand and say I'd like a hot dog with 3 toppings.  Ketchup, mustard and we will let the next random stranger tell us the third topping.  A sql injector might walk up and say, "ketchup, mustard and 'give me all the money in the drawer'". Standard concat queries have no way of discerning that it is an invalid response and therefore hand over what was requested.  A prepared statement will respond with "I dont have a condiment called,"give me all the money in the drawer".

PDO prepared statements are essentially injection proof.  You still have other vulnerabilities like cookie/session hijacking etc, but at least injection is off the table.

Answer (score 0):

Not to rain on Kerrek's parade, but there is one, relatively, universal solution. I use the following and it's always worked:

`$safe_value = mysql_real_escape_string( strip_tags( trim( $value ) ), $db_connection ); // This is if you aren't storing any html tags`

`$safe_value = mysql_real_escape_string( html_entities( trim( $value ) ), $db_connection ); // This is if you are storing html tags`

Hope this helps.

Comment: But isn't `addslashes()` better since it does not assume that you're using mysql and works  similarly?

Comment: `addslashes` is pretty much the same as `mysql_real_escape_string`, and does primarily the same thing. The plus side is that `addslashes` does not require an active database connection to work. It should do the job just the same.

Comment: Sorry to rain on your parade boys, but `addslashes` is not nearly as safe. Check out this vulnerability: http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string

Comment: Speed-read his link, he's right. It doesn't properly escape quotes as well as `mysql_real_escape_string`. You'll want to modify your code to utilize an active database connection for safer values.

Comment: Trading safety for comfort is a touchy subject... if you are talking to mysql, you should escape for mysql, in my opinion. There's no shortcut to that. @Dark: Perhaps you have good reason for your `$safe_value`s, but for my taste they're combining too many disparate notions into one opaque variable. Fine if you can handle that, I'm just stating my feelings about this.

Answer (score -1):

If you know exactly what kind of input you are expecting, better use preg_replace()
If you know that you only expect alpha-numerics:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
 $page = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/', '', $_GET['page']);
 include_once($includeDir.'/'.$page.'.php');
}
?>
```

The above should prevent all attacks executed via GET or POST too, but it assumes you only expect alphanumeric input. Well, I mostly had in mind directory traversal attack, but if you use the GET variable to query a database or display it as a html entity should prevent any attack.
A http://mydomain.tld?index.php?page=../../etc/passwd request won't read your passwd file from your website's /var/www document root but will only try to include a etcpasswd.php file